# How can I access a value from callback function outside of the callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I call a function that takes a callback function parameter.

I want to push the value given to the callback onto a new array so I can use it somewhere else. Problem is that the array stays empty whatever I do.

```
var testarray = new Array();

Getfirstpictures(id, function(myarray) {
    testarray.push(myarray[0]);
});

alert(testarray);
```

Comment: This doesn't parse. You're not closing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Since it uses a callback, it is a pretty safe bet that `Getfirstpictures` is an asynchronous function.

You are calling `alert` before whatever triggers the callback has happened.

You need to wait until the trigger has occurred (usually by putting the alert **inside the callback** function.

Answer (score 0):

Use your callback:

```
    Getfirstpictures(id, function(myarray)
    {
        alert(myarray);
    });
```

That call back is not executed immediately. It is executed by your Getfirpictures method.

---

EDIT:

Change:

```
var testarray = new Array();

Getfirstpictures(id, function(myarray) {
    testarray.push(myarray[0]);
});

alert(testarray);
```

to:

```
Getfirstpictures(id, function(myarray) {
     alert(myarray);
});
```

and it will work. So you can also do something like this:

```
Getfirstpictures(id, function(myarray) {
     doSomething(myarray);
});

function doSomething(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        alert(arr[i]); // or add elements to the DOM etc etc
}
```

Comment: So can you help me what I have to do exactly

Comment: I've added an update. Now if you want to do more with myarray; simply call another function with it.